# Длина динамического массива

Tags: массивы, динамические-массивы

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать програму которая находит в тексте расположение больших букв и записывает ето расположение в массив. Уже все проверил, все равно массив на еденицу меньший. В даной програме должно виводиться 0 40 76 104 123 и длина 5. Виводиться 0 40 76 104 123 и длина 4. Уже не знаю что й делать

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char str[] = {"London is the capital of great britain. Donald trump is a president of usa. A year consist of 365 days. Orange is a fruit. I love breaking bad."};    
    int *arrBig = (int*)malloc(500 * sizeof(int));
    int numMasForBig = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (*(str + i) >= 65 && *(str + i) <= 90)
        {
            numMasForBig++;
            arrBig[numMasForBig] = i;
        }
    }
    arrBig[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arrBig); i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arrBig[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%d ", sizeof(arrBig));


    free(arrBig);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 за слово "записует". `sizeof(arrBig)` - размер указателя, не имеет к длине массива никакого отношения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(arrBig)` - размер указателя, не имеет к длине массива никакого отношения.

```
printf("\n%d ", numMasForBig + 1);
```

Comment: Как же тогда найти длину динамического массива?

Comment: @T.Gryts а чего ее искать, вы его создали сами на 500 элементов